# How to aggregate matched terms in a query_string search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I wish to search wildcard terms in a nested list of dict and then obtain a list of terms and its uuid grouped by matched wildcard.

I've the following mapping in my index:

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "uuid": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "urls": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "url": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "is_visited": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                }
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

and a lot of data such this:

```
{
    "uuid":"afa9ac03-0723-4d66-ae18-08a51e2973bd"
    "urls": [
        {
            "is_visited": true,
            "url": "https://www.google.com"
        },
        {
            "is_visited": false,
            "url": "https://www.facebook.com"
        },
        {
            "is_visited": true,
            "url": "https://www.twitter.com"
        },              
    ]
},
{
    "uuid":"4a1c695d-756b-4d9d-b3a0-cf524d955884"
    "urls": [
        {
            "is_visited": true,
            "url": "https://www.stackoverflow.com"
        },
        {
            "is_visited": false,
            "url": "https://www.facebook.com"
        },
        {
            "is_visited": false,
            "url": "https://drive.google.com"
        },
        {
            "is_visited": false,
            "url": "https://maps.google.com"
        },                      
    ]
}
...
```

I wish to search via wildcard `"*google.com OR *twitter.com"` and obtain something like this:

```
"hits": [
    "*google.com": [
        {
            "uuid": "4a1c695d-756b-4d9d-b3a0-cf524d955884",
            "_source": {
                "is_visited": false,
                "url": "https://drive.google.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "4a1c695d-756b-4d9d-b3a0-cf524d955884",
            "_source": {
                "is_visited": false,
                "url": "https://maps.google.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "uuid":"afa9ac03-0723-4d66-ae18-08a51e2973bd",
            "_source": {
                "is_visited": true,
                "url": "https://www.google.com"
            }
        }
    ]
    "*twitter.com": [
        {
            "uuid":"afa9ac03-0723-4d66-ae18-08a51e2973bd",
            "_source": {
                "is_visited": true,
                "url": "https://www.twitter.com"
            },  
        },
    ]
]
```

This is my (python) search query:

```
body = {
  #"_source": False,
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "urls",
            "query":{
                "query_string":{
                    "query": f"urls.url:{urlToSearch}",
                }
            }
            ,"inner_hits": {
                "size":100 # returns top 100 results
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it returns an hit for each matched term instead of aggregate them in a list similar to what I would like to get.

**EDIT**
This is my setting and mapping:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "char_filter": {
                "my_filter": {
                    "type": "mapping",
                    "mappings": [
                        "- => _",
                    ]
                },
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "char_filter": [
                        "my_filter"
                    ],
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "uuid": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "urls": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "url": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "is_visited": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch will not provide the output you want the way you set up the query.
This scenario to be an aggregation. My suggestion was to apply the nested query and use aggregation on the results.

Attention point [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html):

> Avoid beginning patterns with * or ?. This can increase the iterations
> needed to find matching terms and slow search performance.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "urls",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "urls.url": {
                  "value": "*google.com"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "urls.url": {
                  "value": "*twitter.com"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "agg_providers": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "urls"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "google.com": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "urls.url",
            "include": ".*google.com",
            "size": 10
          }
        },
        "twitter.com": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "urls.url",
            "include": ".*twitter.com",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
"aggregations": {
    "agg_providers": {
      "doc_count": 7,
      "twitter.com": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "https://www.twitter.com",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      "google.com": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "https://drive.google.com",
            "doc_count": 1
          },
          {
            "key": "https://maps.google.com",
            "doc_count": 1
          },
          {
            "key": "https://www.google.com",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, I use `query_search` (eg. `"*google.com OR *twitter.com"` since I have dynamic keywords), but It doesn't work. It doesn't even work with your query, that returns a json result without aggregations.

Comment: there's probably something you haven't mentioned. my query works with the data you provided.
You have to use Wildcard Query. How does my query not return aggs?

Comment: I edited my original post with index mapping and settings. So, I tried wildcard with your query but no aggs are returned

Comment: I did a new test with the mapping you reported and I can see the aggs. Maybe you're confusing the aggs with the hits, these really are empty.

Comment: I did a `curl` request and the result is similar to yours! I think there is a bug in python library or an argument to pass

Comment: The python query was wrong! This is the correct worked query:
```response = es.search(index=INDEX, query=body.get("query"), aggs=body.get("aggs"), size="0")```

Comment: just a last question, please: how can I include others field in `buckets` list result such as `uuid` in addition to `key` and `doc_count`? Thanks.